# For which x the matrix above is the covariance matrix?

Tags: probability, covariance

For which x the matrix above is the covariance matrix?

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & x \\ x & 1 & x \\ x & x & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}

I only understand it must be positively-definite, but how to prove that all these matrices are realizable with some vector $(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3)$?

Comment: What do you mean by **the** covariance matrix?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is positive definite and symmetric then it can be diagonalised by a rotation in 3-space so it is sufficient to prove that all diagonal matrices with positive eigenvalues are realizable. But that can easily be achieved using 3 independent variables with the appropriate variances.

The solution to the original problem is then obtained by rotating the 3 variables back, which gives linear combinations of them.

Thus it is sufficient to find all $x$ for which the matrix is positive definite.